# Optimizing Swiffy Flash to HTML5 loading in UIWebView

Tags: javascript, html, performance, uiwebview, google-swiffy

I'm loading fairly large HTML5/Javascript files that are generated from the Swiffy tool, which converts Flash files to HTML5 and Javascript monstrosities. The JS files are between 300KB-1MB. The files take several seconds to load in a UIWebView on a 3rd generation iPad. There might be nothing to do besides simplifying the animations, but I just wanted to check to see if there were any optimization tricks that I might be missing.

Comment: Could you compress the swiffy-object with something like http://msgpack.org/? it would make the size smaller, but it would make uncompressing more cpu intensive

Comment: Compressing the object would reduce file size, but my main issue is trying to reduce the CPU time of loading the Swiffy object.

Comment: You could use something like web workers (multithreaded JavaScript) to defer the loading of swiffy to its own thread. I don't know if UiWebView supports it but ios safari does.

Comment: I've had to deal with this problem a lot.  One suggestion is to optimize your shapes in Flash prior to publishing.  This will greatly reduce the file size and even more improve playback performance.  You'll be surprised by the impact.  Run the optimize command several times till it no longer has an effect or you reach the limit of what you're willing to visually compromise.